# How do I resolve WalletLoginError in web3auth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm currently working on web3auth authentication, In their documentation most of the code is in typescript. But I'm using javascript in my Next.js project. I'm using core packages to build custom ui interface. But getting this wallet error when I tried to login using walletAdapters

This is my code for that

```
    const web3AuthCoreCtorParams = {
      clientId,
      chainConfig: {
        chainNamespace: CHAIN_NAMESPACES.EIP155,
        chainId: "0x1",
        rpcTarget:
          "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9aa3d95b3bc440fa88ea12eaa4456161", // This is the testnet RPC we have added, please pass on your own endpoint while creating an app
      },
    };

    // creating new web3auth instance
    const web3AuthInstance = new Web3AuthCore(web3AuthCoreCtorParams);

    subscribeAuthEvents(web3AuthInstance);

    const openloginAdapter = new OpenloginAdapter({
      adapterSettings: {
        clientId,
        network: "testnet",
        uxMode: "redirect",
      },
    });

        web3AuthInstance.configureAdapter(openloginAdapter);

    const web3authProvider = await web3AuthInstance.connectTo(
      WALLET_ADAPTERS.OPENLOGIN,
      {
        relogin: true,
        loginProvider: "discord",
      }
    );

    setProvider(web3authProvider);
  };
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
WalletLoginError: Failed to connect with walletFailed to login with openlogin

Call Stack
Function.fromCode
node_modules/@web3auth/base/dist/base.esm.js (315:0)
Function.connectionError
node_modules/@web3auth/base/dist/base.esm.js (320:0)
OpenloginAdapter.connect
node_modules/@web3auth/openlogin-adapter/dist/openloginAdapter.esm.js (141:12)
async Web3AuthCore.connectTo
node_modules/@web3auth/core/dist/core.esm.js (105:0)
```

I'm using version 1.0.0

Comment: I think you should change chainId to 0x4 for testnet Rinkeby and try again

Comment: Did you by any chance found the solution to this ?

Comment: @Adina, No, I didn't so I moved the codebase to typescript as they mentioned in their docs, then It worked.